# How to get started with MapReduce using Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I've heard of Hadoop, but what else can I use to start in this topic...

- what other API are there?
- In general what is it needed to start
  programming here?
- what do you recommend to learn this
  interesting issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the [home page](http://hadoop.apache.org/) of the project, read about it as much as you can, set it up on you local machine. Follow instructions from [this site](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) for setting it up. I recommend these two books if you want to go deeper:

[Hadoop: The definitive guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596521981)

[Pro hadoop](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219424)

Answer (score 3):

great tutorial about hadoop http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

Check out Cloudera's web site, for additional useful resources on hadoop

Answer (score 2):

And once you have gone through learning the basic approach you might want to look at a very integrated way of using Hadoop: http://redmine.z2-environment.net/projects/z2-environment/wiki/How_to_Hadoop (Disclaimer: I am one of the authors)

Answer (score 1):

Second the Cloudera & Yahoo links above. Also, check out this paper I just wrote on the topic for some additional tips: http://images.globalknowledge.com/wwwimages/whitepaperpdf/WP_CL_Learning_Hadoop.pdf